# Using PHP Tags in eval()

Tags: php

I have a textarea where you can write PHP & HTML (or technically 
anything else). You can preview your Code in the browser by submitting 
the form and what I wanna do is `eval()` the code (and thereby display) 
it. Now eval doesn't seem to accept PHP-Tags (`<?php ?>`) in the 
given string. I've read many posts that suggest calling eval like

```
eval(' ?>'.$_POST['markup']);
```

But that my have worked once, but it doesn't work anymore. I get a 
Syntax error for the lines where there's a PHP opening / closing tag.

Is there still a way to `eval()` strings that contain PHP opening and closing tags?

Comment: not an answer but this is super dangerous. Do you 100% trust your users, or indeed, your web application security?

Comment: Are you trying to give users a way to execute their own PHP against your server? That seems like a bad idea. If not, what is your goal here?

Comment: I'm hoping you are aware of the enormous security hole you are creating by doing this. While this might seem like a good idea during development, there is a big chance that it will come back and bite you real hard somewhere down the road.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Of course I know the risk. That part of the project is intended for the developers who are allowed to do anything anyway. It is a quick way to test some code in the browser. And I know, eval is evil per se, but that we need that feature as a quick way to preview code.

Comment: Ok, it was my bad. It does work using "?>" in eval. My Problem was that I didn't use stripslashes on $_POST['markup'] so I got a syntax-error.

Answer (score 6):

The construct

```
eval('?>' . $code);
```

should still work.  Quoting [the documentation](http://www.php.net/eval):

> To mix HTML output and PHP code you can use a closing PHP tag to leave PHP mode.

Please check which kind of syntax error you get, and ensure that the code you supply to `eval()` is correct.

Also remember that `eval()` is **evil**, since it allows users of your script to execute arbitrary code on the server, like reading private files and change/delete data.  This is a serious security risk!

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
<?php

$_POST['markup'] = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' . PHP_EOL;

// First time
eval(' ?>'.$_POST['markup']);

// Second time
eval(' ?>'.$_POST['markup']);
```

... prints this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```